# Sorting objects within a Set by a String value that all objects contain

Tags: java, sorting, object, set

Ok this is a tricky one. I have a list of Sets. I would like to sort the objects in the Sets in an order.

Imagine each set as repressenting a class in a school. Each set contains person objects. A person object holds a String value for name. I'd like to arrange the Persons in the Set by name before I loop through and write them out.

Is there anywahy to use `Collections.sort();` or something similar to achieve this?

```
for (Set<Person> s : listOfAllChildren) {       
      for (Person p : s) {
        if(p.getClass().equalsIgnoreCase("Jones")){
          System.out.println(p.getName());
          }
         else if...//carry on through other classes 
        }                              
      }
```

*I do know that 2+ children in a class may share the same name but please ignore this*

Comment: `if` at line 2 is unnecessary.

Comment: I hope, the `p.getClass()` in line 3 is just a typo and you **do not** have one individual class for each individual or family ;-)

Comment: @Andreas_D: There is only one class for Person, but many person objects created from this class. Is this a problem? The getClass method returns the teachers name for that class.The Person objects are dynamically made from Spreadsheet data.

Comment: I changed the title to reflect the fact that it's a Set you want to sort. Roll back if you disagree.

Comment: [`getClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) does not return a String (teachers name) but a `Class` object. You can compare it to a String but the result will always be `false`. And a class that "redefines" `getClass()` to return a String will not compile.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `Set` has no notion of *ordering* because, well, it's a set.

There is a `SortedSet` interface implemented by `TreeSet` class that you can use. Simply provide an appropriate `Comparator` to the constructor, or let your `Person` class implements `Comparable`.

Answer (score 15):

With Java 8 you can sort the `Set` of persons and generate `List` of persons which are sorted as follows.

```
List<Person> personList = personSet.stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> 
e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO.

Comment: A method ref way of doing same code:
List<Person> personList = personSet.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 10):

You must implement [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for your sortable objects (`Person` etc).

Then:

1. Convert Set to List (some info [here](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/373.html)) since you can't sort a `Set`
2. Use [`Collections.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

or

1. Convert to a [SortedSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (like a [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html))
2. Use a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for custom ordering

Examples:

```
import java.util.*;

class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String firstName, lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) { this.firstName = firstName; this.lastName = lastName;}
    public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}
    public String getLastName() {return lastName;}
    public String getName() {return firstName + " " + lastName;}

    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return lastName.compareTo(p.lastName);
    }
}

class FirstNameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2){
            return p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
    }
}

class Test {
  public static void log(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();
        people.add(new Person("Bob", "Jones"));
        people.add(new Person("Alice", "Yetti"));

        log("Sorted list:");
        List<Person> peopleList = new LinkedList<Person>();
        peopleList.addAll(people);
        Collections.<Person>sort(peopleList);
        for (Person p : peopleList) {
            log(p.getName());
        }

        log("TreeSet:");
        TreeSet<Person> treeSet = new TreeSet<Person>();
        treeSet.addAll(people);
        for (Person p : treeSet) {
            log(p.getName());
        }

        log("TreeSet (custom sort):");
        TreeSet<Person> treeSet2 = new TreeSet<Person>(new FirstNameComparator());
        treeSet2.addAll(people);
        for (Person p : treeSet2) {
            log(p.getName());
        }
      }
};
```

Comment: +1 Searched all around the web to find how to implement compareTo against String. Thank you! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using TreeSet to store objects. And when sorting create new TreeSet with custom comparator for your Person objects. I do not suggest using Collection.sort because AFAIR it can sort only lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your Person class implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface as shown [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) and then sort them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This you can definitely use Collection.sort(). But you will need to either use a sorted set (like TreeSet). Or, alternatively, you can first insert all the elements in the Set to a List.

Then, your Person class needs to implement Comparable, as this interface will be called by the Collections.sort() when it tries to decide in which order to place them. So it can be something simple like:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
  ...
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Person p) {
    return this.name.compareTo(p.name);
  }
}
```

If using a TreeSet, it should be sorted already. Otherwise, if using a List, simply call Collections.sort(List l) on each list.

Comment: +1 because I made the same mistake and now quit. You updated your answer and still fighting ;). I always confuse `Set` with `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using a `SortedSet` for example a `TreeSet`. This allows you to provide a `Comparator` which in your case can compare the name of the `Person`.