# Sorting objects in Set in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, treeset

I know that we can use TreeSet to sort Strings and numbers in an natural order. What if there is a Set of objects?

For example:

```
I have a Person class
{
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private int age;

}
```

Set person = new TreeSet();

I want *person* sorted by firstName when I initialize *person*.

Comment: Have a look at `Comparable` and Oracle's [object ordering tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

Comment: I think this post can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132367/sorting-objects-within-a-set-by-a-string-value-that-all-objects-contain

Comment: Look at the my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42123307/3845396) for similar question.

Answer (score 2):

Both `Comparable` and `Comparator` work for you, but I suggest `Comparator` because it doesn't require you modify `Person` class, you only need the write an implementation class based on the sorting attribute, therefore `Comparator` is much more flexiable:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class FirstNameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        String name1 = o1.getFirstName();
        String name2 = o2.getFirstName();
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }

}

//instantiate TreeSet instance with FirstNameComparator
Set<Person> ts = new TreeSet<>(new FirstNameComparator());
```

Comment: `Collections.sort` takes in a `List`, so that won't work with a `Set`. But, since OP is using `TreeSet`, there's a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Comparator)) that accepts a `Comparator`, which would work here.

Comment: *I suggest `Comparator` because it doesn't require you modify `Person` class*. There's nothing wrong with modifying a class that should have natural ordering. A much stronger argument is that a class like `Person` probably *doesn't* have a single natural order.

Comment: @MickMnemonic thanks Mick. My fault, I thought it took iterable.

Comment: @shmosel thanks for your comment and you're right. What I thought was we might not control over the class `Person`.